# Definitionless, private function

Tags: dart

I am new to dart, and I am not familiar with this concept. Some patience is appreciated.

I was reading some code, [here](https://github.com/munificent/hauberk/blob/master/lib/src/engine/stage/tile.dart), when I came across this. (line 14)

```
static final none = Motility._(0);
```

Looking at the second half of the assignment, I can see a private function that takes an integer, but after some searching I do not see a definition in the class.

So, my question is what is this mysterious function? I am assuming this is a feature of the language, but I am having trouble looking it up since I have never heard of this concept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It invokes the constructor

```
Motility._(this._bitMask);
```

https://github.com/munificent/hauberk/blob/master/lib/src/engine/stage/tile.dart#L28

It is not that obvious anymore since `new` became optional, but it is a common pattern to have private constructors. (Identifiers starting with `_` are private in Dart)

`Motility` is basically an enum that is built this way instead of

```
enum Motility { none, door, fly, swim, walk, doorAndFly, doorAndWalk, flyAndWalk }
```

because this way custom values can be assigned.

Comment: Oh! So, `int_bitmask = 0` is a private field to the class with a default value of 0, right? If that is true, then the constructor is simply assigning a value to that field.

Comment: Yes, the `static final ...` will each hold a singleton `Motility` instance (singleton per unique `_bitMask` value) with the `_bitMask` fields initialized to `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, .... So if your app uses `Motility.fly` two times in your app both will point to exactly the same `Motility` instance (with `_bitMask` `2`)

Comment: Does this mean motility has instances of itself?

Comment: Yup, looks like that

Comment: That broke my mind for a second. After considering the fact that they are static, it makes a bit more sense!